# Ignore Empty DataFrame while reading a file with panda in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file like this:

```
`Empty DataFrame 
 Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 Index: []
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 Index: []
                       0                         1                           2  \
46   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/551    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
47   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/550    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/C/34         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
48   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/553    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/30         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
49   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/552    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
50   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/1199   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/1058       RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   

     3   4  
46 NaN NaN  
47 NaN NaN  
48 NaN NaN  
49 NaN NaN  
50 NaN NaN`
```

And I want to read it into an array with 3 columns. For now I tried using `pd.read_csv(self.filename,delim_whitespace=True)`, but that gives me a lot of errors while trying to read `Empty DataFrame` part. How can I make program ignore this part?

**Edit:**
Optimal solution would be if there was no Empty DataFrames in my file. The file is an effect of searching in many files, among which some are empty. I thought I had filtered empty files by giving an exception so that effect of searching in empty files would not be stored in results. I suppose I did it in the wrong way. Can somebody please correct me?

```
from numpy import numpy.mean as nm
def find_same_direction_chain(self, results):
         separation= lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x.split('/')])
         left_chain=self.data[0].apply(separation)
         right_chain=self.data[1].apply(separation)
         i=1
         try:
            while i<len(self.data[:])-5:
                if nm(left_chain[2][i:i+3])>=nm(left_chain[2][i+2:i+5])  and nm(right_chain[2][i:i+3])>=nm(right_chain[2][i+2:i+5]) and len(self.data[:])>0:   
                    if nm(left_chain[2][i+2:i+5])>=nm(left_chain[2][i+4:i+7])  and nm(right_chain[2][i+2:i+5])>=nm(right_chain[2][i+4:i+7]):   
                        results.chains.append(str(self.filename+", "+str(i)+self.data[0:3][i:i+5]))

                else: pass
                i+=1
         except ValueError:
                    results.bin.append(self.filename)
         except TypeError:
                    results.data_structure_error.append(self.filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Empty DataFrame 
 Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 Index: []
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 Index: []
                       0                         1                           2  \
46   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/551    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
47   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/550    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/C/34         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
48   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/553    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/30         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
49   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/552    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33         RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   
50   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/1199   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/1058       RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis   

     3   4  
46 NaN NaN  
47 NaN NaN  
48 NaN NaN  
49 NaN NaN  
50 NaN NaN"""
```

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True, names=range(7))

#remove rows with NaN in columns 0 - 3
df = df.dropna(subset=[0,1,2,3])

#remove rows where first column contains text 'Columns'
df = df[~df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('Columns')] 

#shift first row
df.iloc[0,:] = df.iloc[0,:].shift(-3)

#set first column to index
df = df.set_index(df.iloc[:,0])
#remove unnecessary columns
df = df.drop([0,4,5,6], axis=1)
print df
                           1                         2                      3
0                                                                            
46   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/551    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
47   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/550    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/C/34  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
48   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/553    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/30  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
49   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/552    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
50  RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/1199  RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/1058  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
```

Or solution with `skiprows` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True, names=range(7), skiprows=6)

#remove rows with NaN
df = df.dropna(subset=[0,1,2,3])

#shift first row
df.iloc[0,:] = df.iloc[0,:].shift(-3)

#set first column to index
df = df.set_index(df.iloc[:,0])
#remove unnecessary columns
df = df.drop([0,4,5,6], axis=1)
print df
                           1                         2                      3
0                                                                            
46   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/551    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
47   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/550    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/C/34  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
48   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/553    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/30  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
49   RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/552    RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/A/33  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
50  RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/U/1199  RNA/4v6p.csv,46AA/G/1058  RNA/4v6p.csv,46WW_cis
```

EDIT:

You can try change (I have no sample data, so untested):

```
results.chains.append(str(self.filename+", "+str(i)+self.data[0:3][i:i+5]))
```

to:

```
if len(self.data[0:3][i:i+5]) > 0:                      
    results.chains.append(str(self.filename+", "+str(i)+self.data[0:3][i:i+5]))
```

Comment: I suppose I cant use skiprows, because in my file Empty DataFrame part is placed irregularly.

Comment: Ok, try first  solution without `skiprows`.

Comment: But maybe better is filter empty `DataFrames` before writing to file - e.g. `print [df for df in dfs if len(df) > 0]` (dfs is `list` of `DataFrames`)

Comment: This is probably what I need although when conditions of certain elements in DataFrame are met I save them into a list like: `results.chains.append(str(self.filename+", "+str(i)+self.data[0:3][i:i+5]))`, and then I save this list into a file with `with     open("chains.txt","a+") as f:`
    `f.write("\n".join(self.result.chains))` so I wonder, why there are empty DataFrames in my file? How did they get there?

Comment: I think problem is if in your list of `DataFrames` `results`, they are empty `df`. Maybe you read empty files.

Comment: yes indeed, some of them are empty. I think you're totally right and I thought I did that (filtered empty files), but apparently I didn't, therefore I edited my question. It would be great if you could help me with this.

Comment: I think it is really hard to help you, because this is uncompleted code `nm`, testing data are missing. But if `results` is `list` of `DataFrames`, try check code with `append` and where empty `df` are created, add `if len(self.data[0:3][i:i+5]) > 0:                      
                            results.chains.append(str(self.filename+", "+str(i)+self.data[0:3][i:i+5]))` but without data in cannot be tested.